# Code formated with pre tag copy/paste problem

Tags: formatting, internet-explorer-8, code

I have created a blog on Blogger and would like to display some short code snippets in my posts. I used pre tag with some simple formatting (no syntax highlighting). When displayed in browser code looks fine, but when I try to copy and paste it to Notepad, the text is all on one line. Here is what this looks like:

http://theartofoffice.blogspot.com/

(hopefully it is all right to post the address here). This happens only with Internet Explorer (I use IE 8), while Firefox, Opera and Google Chrome handle copy / paste correctly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't IE7 copy <pre><code> blocks to the clipboard correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136443/why-doesnt-ie7-copy-precode-blocks-to-the-clipboard-correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the comment. Actually, I was able to fix the issue by setting an option: Blogger Dashboard -> Settings -> Formatting -> Convert Line Breaks = No.

[image]

Now there are no br tags inside my pre tags and IE8 copies the snippets correctly.